# How to avoid the eslint-plugin-import "unresolved path to module 'electron'" error

Tags: electron, eslint

Ok, so this is documented plain as day, yet I'm probably doing something stupid and can't get it to work...

I'm using the eslint-plugin-import on an Electron app and I'm getting a lint error of `Unable to resolve path to module 'electron'`.

In the docs, it says I need to either A.) use the shared Electron config B.) pass in an array with `electron` in to the "import/core-modules" setting.

for A, I tried this:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:import/electron"
  ]
}
```

and when I lint, I get this:

[image]

for B, I tried:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "import"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "import/core-modules": [
      "electron"
    ]
  }
}
```

and get this:

[image]

I've also tried:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "import"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/core-modules": [
      "electron"
    ]
  }
}
```

and I just get the "unresolved path to module' error.

It's probably something really silly, but what am I doing wrong? Ideally I'd just like to use the shared config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after posting this issue on the Github repo, turns out that the Electron related changes have not been released to npm yet. They will be in the next release, but as of now, they are only in master.

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/393#issuecomment-227821876